# Customization of TinyMCE Text Editor

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, tinymce

How i can customize TinyMCE in my asp.net application so when i enter text in text area of tinyMCE i am able to see its preview and design mode ?

Here is script

```
 <script src="../tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       tinyMCE.init({
           // General options
           mode: "textareas",
           theme: "advanced",
             plugins : "preview",

           plugins: "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

           // Theme options
           theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
           theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
           theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
           theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
           theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
           theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
           theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
           theme_advanced_resizing: true,

           // Skin options
           skin: "o2k7",
           skin_variant: "silver",

           // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
           content_css: "css/example.css",

           // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
           template_external_list_url: "js/template_list.js",
           external_link_list_url: "js/link_list.js",
           external_image_list_url: "js/image_list.js",
           media_external_list_url: "js/media_list.js",

           // Replace values for the template plugin
           template_replace_values: {
               username: "Some User",
               staffid: "991245"
           }
       });
</script>
```

here is my text area code

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtBody" runat="server" Width="400px" TextMode="Multiline" Height="300px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Currently it is not showing any button of preview and design mode.

Comment: i do not understand your problem

Comment: @Thariama how i can add preview and design mode on bottom of tinymce?

Comment: with "preview" you mean the html-button?

Comment: It will be HTML button or any built in tab of TinyMCE.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to have the button toolbar on bottom of tinymce all you need to do is to use the config param [theme_advanced_toolbar_location](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3atheme_advanced_toolbar_location)

```
theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "bottom",
```

Answer (score 0):

We use the TinyMCE preview plugin like this in our Rails application:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '<%= selector.html_safe -%>',
    theme: "modern",
    height: <%= height -%>,
    plugins: [
      "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
      "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
      "save table contextmenu paste textcolor"
      ],
    //content_css: "css/content.css",
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect | bold italic forecolor backcolor | link image media | code preview print fullscreen",
    style_formats: [
       { title: 'Content', block: 'div', classes: 'content' }
    ],
    file_browser_callback : myFileBrowser
});
```

As you can see there is a 'preview' plugin item and 'preview' toolbar item in the listings. You might need to add your own toolbar config option then it will show up.